# Ember.js ember-plupload drag&drop

Tags: javascript, ember.js, drag-and-drop, plupload

I want to create a drag & drop upload file ember.js app, I'm trying to use ember-plupload, but I can't make the plupload work, here is my code:

```
{{#pl-uploader for="upload-image" extensions="jpg jpeg png gif" onfileadd="uploadImage" as |queue dropzone|}}
  <div class="dropzone" id={{dropzone.id}}>
    {{#if dropzone.active}}
      {{#if dropzone.valid}}
        Drop to upload
      {{else}}
        Invalid
      {{/if}}
    {{else if queue.length}}
      Uploading {{queue.length}} files. ({{queue.progress}}%)
    {{else}}
      <h4>Upload Images</h4>
      <p>
        {{#if dropzone.enabled}}
          Drag and drop images onto this area to upload them or
        {{/if}}
        <a id="upload-image">Add an Image.</a>
      </p>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
{{/pl-uploader}}
{{outlet}}
```

It's the sample template from plupload. And a route:

```
import Ember from "ember";

const get = Ember.get;
const set = Ember.set;

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  actions: {
    uploadImage: function (file) {
      var product = this.modelFor('product');
      var image = this.store.createRecord('image', {
        product: product,
        filename: get(file, 'name'),
        filesize: get(file, 'size')
      });

      file.read().then(function (url) {
        if (get(image, 'url') == null) {
          set(image, 'url', url);
        }
      });

      file.upload('/api/images/upload').then(function (response) {
        set(image, 'url', response.headers.Location);
        return image.save();
      }, function () {
        image.rollback();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Sample again. Finally there is the result, the page

> Upload Images
>
> Drag and drop images onto this area to upload them or Add an Image.

But I can't drag anything onto it. And a firebug log:

> Instantiating FileInput... 
>   Trying runtime: html5 
>  Object {accept=[1],
>   name="file", multiple=true, ...} 
>    default mode: browser 
> selected
>   mode: false 
> Runtime 'html5' failed to initialize 
> Trying runtime: html4
>   
> Object {accept=[1], name="file", multiple=true, ...} 
>  default mode:
>   browser 
>     selected mode: false 
>  Runtime 'html4' failed to initialize 
>   Trying runtime: flash 
>  Object {accept=[1], name="file", multiple=true,
>   ...} 
>        select_multiple: true (compatible modes: null) 
>        drag_and_drop:
>   true (compatible modes: null) 
>   default mode: client 
>         send_browser_cookies: false (compatible modes: client) 
>         select_file: true (compatible modes: client) 
>  selected mode: false 
>   Runtime 'flash' failed to initialize 
> Trying runtime: silverlight 
>   Object {accept=[1], name="file", multiple=true, ...} 
>         select_multiple: true (compatible modes: null)  
>   drag_and_drop: true
>   (compatible modes: null) 
>    default mode: browser 
>         send_browser_cookies: false (compatible modes: client) 
>         select_file: true (compatible modes: client) 
>  Silverlight is not
>   installed or minimal version (2.0.31005.0) requirement not met (not
>   likely). 
>    selected mode: false 
> Runtime 'silverlight' failed to
>   initialize 
>  Instantiating FileDrop...
>  Trying runtime: html5
>  Object
>   {accept=[1], required_caps=Object, ...} 
>     default mode: browser 
>     selected mode: false 
>  Runtime 'html5' failed to initialize
>  Trying
>   runtime: html4
>  Object {accept=[1], required_caps=Object, ...} 
>     default
>   mode: browser     
> selected mode: false
>  Runtime 'html4' failed to
>   initialize 
> Trying runtime: flash
>  Object {accept=[1],
>   required_caps=Object, ...}    
>   select_multiple: true (compatible modes:
>   null)     
>   drag_and_drop: true (compatible modes: null) 
>  default mode:
>   client    
>   drag_and_drop: true (compatible modes: null) 
>         send_browser_cookies: false (compatible modes: client) 
>         select_file: true (compatible modes: client) 
>  selected mode: false 
>   Runtime 'flash' failed to initialize 
> Trying runtime: silverlight 
>   Object {accept=[1], required_caps=Object, ...}    
>   select_multiple: true 
>   (compatible modes: null)  
>   drag_and_drop: true (compatible modes:
>   null) 
>   default mode: browser   
>   drag_and_drop: true (compatible modes:
>   null) 
>       send_browser_cookies: false (compatible modes: client) 
>         select_file: true (compatible modes: client) 
>  Silverlight is not
>   installed or minimal version (2.0.31005.0) requirement not met (not
>   likely). 
>    selected mode: false 
>  Runtime 'silverlight' failed to
>   initialize

What can I do in that case? Greetings, Rafał

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an issue on the author's github page, and the problem was solved immediately, so the case is closed, and Thanks for Tim for a great support.
 There is a new, working version of ember-plupload.

Greetings, Rafał